# Window and document as jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery

Why, in jQuery, could we use `$(document)` as a selector, but have to use `$('body')` with quotes or double quotes around the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `body` is an element and [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document) is an object.

> Each web page loaded in the browser has its own document object. This object serves as an entry point to the web page's content (the DOM tree, including elements such as `<body>` and `<table>`) and provides functionality global to the document (such as obtaining the page's URL and creating new elements in the document).

Answer (score 2):

`document` is a global js object in the scope of the page whereas `<body>` is an element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Document is a defined object on the window object, while body is not defined the same way document is. However you can define it yourself:

```
var body;
$(document).ready(function () {
     body = document.find('body');
});
```

In terms of the window object document exists as a predefinition as this is the root of your window document, or the HTML tag. The DOM then allows you to find all children of the document which includes the body. `window['document']` is equivalent to `window.document` or to `document`, which is the root of your page, however body may be ambiguous, because it does not necessary have to be the first/second/third child of the document, not to mention that it's also optional, which would render always defined body object to be sometimes `undefined`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$(document.body)` instead.

Comment: Alternative is helpful, but OP asked the reason why.